# UWP - "System.IO.IOException: 'Network access is denied : '..."

Tags: c#, uwp

**ANSWERED:**

I created a UWP app for my company. In this app the user has the option to load a file. This is just a simple CSV file that gets parsed. Everything worked fine until I published and ran the app; now I get the error, "System.IO.IOException: 'Network access is denied : '..."

When I read into this problem, a lot of people solved it by including "<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>" in the Package.appxmanifest. So, I did the same however the app is not appearing in the File System privacy settings page for me to manually allow it to have access to my file system.

The capabilities that I have included in the Package.appxmanifest show when I go to install the app. However, it seems like they just aren't working.

I am willing to provide more information and any advice would help, as I am running out of things to try to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:**
I created a new UWP app, and pasted everything from the previous one into it. This new one shows in my File system and the UWP app has access to my file system, but the problem still remains. It still gives me "network access is denied."

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**
If anyone else is having this issue, see if you're using StreamWriter or StreamReader. I used them alongside the Windows.Storage library, and they seemed to have been causing the issues. I removed them and everything works as intended.

Comment: Please try to uninstall previous app and install the new one, reboot your OS check again.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have tried that. I have also tried to install the app on another computer (this one without an antivirus) and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Have you add the Internet capability?